# unable to send data via this.serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using following function to validate and send data to the php server:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function() {
    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
$("#register_form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        register_username: "required",
        register_password: "required",
        register_email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        register_confirm_password: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: '#register_password'
        },
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        register_username: "Please enter your username",
        register_password: "Please enter your password",
        register_confirm_password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            equalTo:"Please enter password same as above."
        },
        register_email: "Please enter a valid email address",
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
         var pdata = $(this).serialize();
         alert(pdata);


        $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/quiz/index.php/signin',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success){
                    console.log("Form is submitted.data is" + data.success);

                    $.each(data, function() {
                        $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                            console.log("key; " + k);
                            console.log("value; " + v);
                        });
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("The data returned is:" + data.success);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    },
});
});

});
```

All the validation works, but the issue is with the line:

```
var pdata = $(this).serialize();
```

I am getting empty pdata:

```
alert(pdata);
```

I don't know why the data is not serialized here. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't serialize $( this )
Try serializing the form instead.

```
$( "#register_form" ).serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` isn't what you think it is anymore. It's not `#register_form`, but instead the `submitHandler` function.

If you do `console.log(pdata)` you should see the function definition in your console.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the `submitHandler` function is not the `form` element, so `this` is not pointing to the element you require. It does however provide you with a parameter, which you've named `form`, that you can use instead, like this:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/quiz/index.php/signin',
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        // your code...
```